# Print out from Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby

```
address = [1,2,3]
p address
new_address = address.reverse!
p new_address
p address.reverse!
```

Prints:

```
[1,2,3]
[3,2,1]
[1,2,3]
```

I don't understand why the last print out is 1,2,3 if it is meant to print the address in reverse, the address is 1,2,3

I expected the last line to be [3,2,1].

Answer (score 0):

To understand why this behavior you need to know what the `!` means:

It indicates that `reverse!` is more dangerous thant `reverse` following the principle **Of least surprise** the developer can transmit that feeling in the syntax to the people who will use it. Here the big diference is that `reverse!` will change the object itself and `reverse` not. https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/conventions-in-ruby-and-the-principle-of-least-surprise/158706/2

So address is:

```
address = [1,2,3]
```

When you call this:

```
new_address = address.reverse! # Address is [3,2,1]
```

And last:

```
p address.reverse! # address is [1, 2, 3]
```

Here the base is to understand that `!` is always modifiying the object itself.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely right regarding the use of `reverse!` vs. `reverse`. But bang methods in Ruby are not always modifying the receiver. The convention is that the `!` indicates that a method is a more dangerous than its non-bang counterpart, see Matz quote here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/conventions-in-ruby-and-the-principle-of-least-surprise/158706/2

Comment: Great point @spickermann thanks for pointing it out, I'm kind of new in `ruby` but in the context of `reverse!` at least it means that will operate over the object it self. I will take in account your explanation to interpret other functions using the `bang (!)` operator.

Comment: Where does that quote / explanation for `!` come from? Can you add a link / source?

Comment: @Stefan removed the quote, I didn't have a clear reference.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby when you have a `!` at the end of the method call that means that it changes the recipient as well.

So `new_address = address.reverse!` not just assigned the reverted value to `new_address` but also to `address`.

I updated your code to make it more visible:

```
address = [1,2,3]
p address
new_address = address.reverse! # [3,2,1]

p address # [3,2,1]
p new_address # [3,2,1]

p address.reverse! # [1,2,3]
```

What you wanted to use is the same method but without `!`

```
address = [1,2,3]
p address
new_address = address.reverse
p new_address
p address.reverse
```

More info: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/objects/bangs.html

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the `bang (!)` in ruby.

```
address = [1,2,3]
p address
#> [1,2,4]

address.reverse
p address
#> [1,2,3]

address.reverse!
p address
#> [3,2,1]
```

Bang or exclamation mark means that you are making a permanent saved change in your code.

some more examples:

```
#without Bang (!).
name = "Ruby Monstas"
puts name.downcase
#> ruby monstas

puts name 
#> Ruby Monstas


# With Bang(!) Operator
name = "Ruby Monstas"
puts name.downcase!
#> ruby monstas

puts name
#> ruby monstas
```

Comment: Bang is not an operator, it’s a naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

The various bang methods (methods that have a exclamation point character at the end of the method name) modify the object **in place**.  Here's what you essentially did in your code:

```
address = [1,2,3]
```

This first line defined your `address` variable as `[1, 2, 3]`

```
p address
```

This second line prints your `address` variable (which is still `[1, 2, 3]`)

```
new_address = address.reverse!
```

This third line both defined your `new_address` variable **AND** modified your original `address` variable in place.  At this point, **both** `new_address` and `address` are defined as `[3, 2, 1]`

```
p new_address
```

This fourth line of code simply prints your `new_address` variable, which of course is `[3, 2, 1]`

```
p address.reverse!
```

Remember how we modified the original `address` variable in place back on the third line?  Well this fifth line of code is simply printing that previously modified variable in reverse, so `[3, 2, 1]` becomes `[1, 2, 3]` again.  Not only that, but again you are modifying the original variable by using the bang version of the `reverse` method.  If at this point you were to try and print your `new_address` variable again, guess what...

```
p new_address
#=>  [1, 2, 3]
```

In this instance, I'm not sure why you would even want to use the `reverse!` method.  I suspect based on your confusion that you should simply be using `reverse`.